# How to find an object key that contains a value within it's array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have the following Javascript (Coffeescript) object:

```
urlSets =
  a: [
    'url-a.com'
    'url-b.com'
    'url-c.com'
    ]
  b: [
    'url-d.com'
    'url-e.com' 
    'url-f.com'
    ]
  c: [
    'url-g.com'
  ]
```

Given i have the value `"url-a.com"`, how do i find the `key` of `urlSets` that contains this url?

I am already using the `underscore.js` library, and figured i'd possibly use `_.findKey` and `_.contains`. I've been toying with something like this:

```
_.findKey urlSets, (key) ->
  return _.contains(key, "url-a.com")
```

…but with no luck. It returns `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: That looks fine. Are you sure that underscore is correctly loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to not use any special libraries for this sort of looping, especially when using coffee script which has such nice loops.

```
foundKey = null

for key, urls of urlSets
  if 'url-a.com' in urls
    foundKey = key

console.log foundKey #=> a
```

It uses a `for key, value of object` loop to easily loop over your `urlSets` object, and then a `if item in array` include check which coffee compiles to an `indexOf` call.

Comment: …except that always enumerates the whole object, and yields the last occurence. `_findKey urlSets, (urls) -> 'url-a.com' in urls` might be easier indeed.

Answer (score -1):

You already tried to use...

```
 var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

 for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
 }
```

If is useful, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in